# Configure prebid server in docker

Tags: mobile, header-bidding, prebid

I want to configure a test environment for integration of prebid mobile SDK. So I deployed the prebid server with Docker, as described here: 
https://github.com/prebid/prebid-server/blob/master/docs/developers/deployment.md

and implemented a test application for iOS as described here: 
http://prebid.org/prebid-mobile/pbm-api/ios/code-integration-ios.html

But I can't find how to configure the prebid server to start working with SDK, f.e.:

- how to register an account and get Account ID
- how to add ad units
  configs

Any ideas about how it could be performed?

Comment: did you get your answer?if yes, please help me out.